# Reorganizing pandas dataframe turning Column into new Header, Original Header to be part of multiindex with a prexisting Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pivot

I have been tasked with reorganizing a fairly large data set for analysis. I want to make a dataframe where each employee has a list of Stats associated with their Employee Number ordered based on how many periods they have been with the company. The data does not go all the way back to the start of the company so some employees will not appear in the first period. My guess is there's some combination of pivot and merge that I am unable to wrap my head around.

df1 looks like this:

```
    Periods since Start   Period   Employee Number   Wage   Sick Days  
0                     3   202001               101     20          14  
1                     2   202001               102     15          12  
2                     1   202001               103     10          17  
3                     4   202002               101     20          14  
4                     3   202002               102     20          10  
5                     2   202002               103     10          13  
6                     5   202003               101     25          13  
7                     4   202003               102     20           9  
8                     3   202003               103     10          13
```

And I want df2 (Column# for reference only):

```
Column1   Column2     Column3   Column4   Column5  
                      101       102       103      
      1   Wage        NaN       NaN       10       
      1   Sick Days   NaN       NaN       17       
      2   Wage        NaN       15        10       
      2   Sick Days   NaN       12        13       
      3   Wage        20        20        10       
      3   Sick Days   14        10        13       
      4   Wage        20        20        NaN      
      4   Sick Days   14        9         NaN
```

Column1 = 'Periods since Start'

Column2 = "Stat" e.g. 'Wage', 'Sick Days'

Column3 - Column 5 Headers = 'Employee Number'

First thoughts were to try pivot/merge/stack but I have had no good results.

The second option I thought of was to create a dataframe with the index and headers that I wanted and then populate it from df1

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

stat_list = ['Wage', 'Sick Days']

largest_period = df1['Periods since Start'].max()

df2 = np.tile(stat_list, largest_period)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2, columns = ['Stat']) 

df2['Period_Number'] = df2.groupby('Stat').cumcount()+1

df2 = pd.DataFrame(index = df2[['Period_Number', 'Stat']], 
                 columns = df1['Employee Number'])
```

Which Yields:

```
Employee Number    101   102   103   
(1, 'Wage')        NaN   NaN   NaN  
(1, 'Sick Days')   NaN   NaN   NaN  
(2, 'Wage')        NaN   NaN   NaN  
(2, 'Sick Days')   NaN   NaN   NaN  
(3, 'Wage')        NaN   NaN   NaN  
(3, 'Sick Days')   NaN   NaN   NaN  
(4, 'Wage')        NaN   NaN   NaN  
(4, 'Sick Days')   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

But I am at a loss on how to populate it.

Comment: kindly accept my answer or Scott Boston's answer as solution by clicking the checkmark next to the answer you select as best solution. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I wanted to run the solution on the full data set before accepting. It's about 200 million data points and I wanted to see if there was an efficiency difference, but am still working on some data QC before I run it. Scott's works well because I don't have to columns (there are more than the example). But if yours was materially faster I was going to accept your answer.

Comment: No worries @JohnAnderson . Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, first `melt` the dataframe keeping Periods since Start, Employee Number, and Period in the index.  Next, `pivot` the dataframe making rows and columns with 'value' from melt the values in the pivoted dataframe.  Lastly, cleanup index with `reset_index` and remove the column index header name using `rename_axis`:

```
df.melt(['Periods since Start', 'Employee Number', 'Period'])\
  .pivot(['Periods since Start', 'variable'], 'Employee Number', 'value')\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Periods since Start   variable   101   102   103
0                    1  Sick Days   NaN   NaN  17.0
1                    1       Wage   NaN   NaN  10.0
2                    2  Sick Days   NaN  12.0  13.0
3                    2       Wage   NaN  15.0  10.0
4                    3  Sick Days  14.0  10.0  13.0
5                    3       Wage  20.0  20.0  10.0
6                    4  Sick Days  14.0   9.0   NaN
7                    4       Wage  20.0  20.0   NaN
8                    5  Sick Days  13.0   NaN   NaN
9                    5       Wage  25.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Hi Scott, nice concise approach. I'm getting `ValueError: Length of passed values is 18, index implies 2.`

Comment: I read in the data as such: `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')` with none of the columns being on the index. Not sure if that is why or if it is a pandas version thing

Comment: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')` Yep, tested it also.

Comment: pandas version? I am using 1.1.2

Comment: it is : `1.0.1`

Comment: Maybe an bug after the 1.0 update.... Can you upgrade? I'll revert and test too.

Comment: Yep, pandas 1.0.1 bug... I reverted back to that version and sure enough, I got that errror.  Let me upgrade again and see if it goes away.

Comment: Confirmed, it works for me. Nice approach +1. By the way, I have always had issues using `pivot` the simple way you have done, which is why I gravitate towards `unstack`. I think the pandas developers finally just "fixed" it in later versions but it has been an issue in older versions.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can `.melt` and then `.unstack` the dataframe.
2. Finish up up with some multiindex column clean up using `.droplevel` and passing `axis=1` to drop unnecessary levels on columns rather than the default `axis=0`, which would drop index columns. You can also use `reset_index()` to bring the index columns into your dataframe:

---

```
df = (df.melt(id_vars=['Periods since Start', 'Employee Number'],
              value_vars=['Wage', 'Sick Days'])
      .set_index(['Periods since Start', 'Employee Number', 'variable']).unstack(1)
      .droplevel(0, axis=1)
      .reset_index())
df
Out[1]: 
Employee Number  Periods since Start   variable   101   102   103
0                                  1  Sick Days   NaN   NaN  17.0
1                                  1       Wage   NaN   NaN  10.0
2                                  2  Sick Days   NaN  12.0  13.0
3                                  2       Wage   NaN  15.0  10.0
4                                  3  Sick Days  14.0  10.0  13.0
5                                  3       Wage  20.0  20.0  10.0
6                                  4  Sick Days  14.0   9.0   NaN
7                                  4       Wage  20.0  20.0   NaN
8                                  5  Sick Days  13.0   NaN   NaN
9                                  5       Wage  25.0   NaN   NaN
```

When melting the dataframe, you can pass `var_name=` as the default is "variable". If you do that make sure to change the column name when using `set_index()` as well.